# Using socket io over http, is a secure log in procedure possible?

Tags: authentication, ssl, https, socket.io, handshake

I have built a game server in nodejs using socket io.

I am planning to remove express and cookies from the authentication procedure and instead use webstorage and a client which attempts to log in during the socket io handshake.

However, I am using http and sending the user id and password in cleartext. Please, have mercy on me! I believe using https for the entire socket connection would add a huge overhead since updates are sent every 100ms. My current solution has worked for development, but I am sure it is insecure.

I should mention I have never set up/used https, so correct me if I am wrong regarding the overhead, which I know is a very debated topic. An ideal solution appears to be authenticating users over a https connection and then transmitting game state stuff over http, but I have no idea if or how this could be achieved.

Finally, I have 2 options for logging users in. I could allow the socket io connection on the server and just emit the log in credentials from the client. Then disconnect them if they are incorrect.
However, a cleaner solution would be to send the user id and pw in the http header for the handshake, and then authenticate the user from a socket.io middleware, but I am not sure if sending the data this way would be safe.

I do not think this is such a niche problem that a standard practice does not exist, however it may be to just use https. I believe there is no advantage to encrypting the users credentials as the data can still be snooped between the client and server. Any information on how I can achieve this is appreciated,
Or just point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Use one https connection for the login authentication and reply back to the client with a unique security token if the username/password is valid.

Use ordinary http connections for the rest of the dialog between client and server.  Include the security token in the dialog if the client is requesting something that requires validation.  Your client can store the security token in a cookie if you find that convenient, as the token can only be used for one session.

Have the server purge session tokens once a client signs off, or after the token has been idle for some period of time.

This is cheap and effective for medium-security applications. Variations on this scheme get used in many applications. It is not foolproof - a packet sniffer may be able to grab the security token in transit.

If the security token is constructed from a hash of the client IP address and a server timestamp, then it is easy for the server to validate the token in every message and very difficult for a 3rd-party to hijack the session.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It makes perfect sense. However, the only sensitive data is sent in the handshake (un/pw). I don think the token would ever be used as I dont intend to athenticate every action a player makes.So surely I could just use simple digest authentication. Since I would be sending the token over http after the handhsake it would be just as susceptible to snooping.

Comment: @MushyShaman - You could exchange an encryption key on the initial SSL connection and then use that to encrypt/decrypt payload of future non-SSL messages.  Not as secure as SSL itself, but might do for your use.